# How to get access to properties of related table via WHERE clause?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

For example I have follow domains:

```
class Company {
    String name 
}

class Employee {
    String firstName
    String secondName
    Company company
}
```

And I try to get all employees where company name is 'M$oft'

```
Employee.where {
   eq 'company.name', 'M$oft'
}.list()
```

Got:

> could not resolve property: company.name of: myapp.Employee

---

Also I try this:

```
Employee.where {
   createAlias('company', 'c')
   eq 'c.name', 'M$oft'
}.list()
```

Got:

> could not resolve property: c of: myapp.Employee

---

I know about:

```
Employee.where {
    company.name == 'M$oft'
}
```

but it's not appropriate for me.

I just want to know: is it possible do it via `where` clause with usage of string names of fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use next syntax:

```
 Employee.where {
   company{
     eq 'name', 'M$oft'
   }
}.list()
```

And don't forget to use ' ' with strings that have $. Maybe some unexpected result.